# MATLAB: applying filter to ROI or mask in greyscale image

Tags: matlab, filter, binary, mask, roi

I have a greyscale image (I), and would like to apply different filters to different regions of that image in matlab (R2015b) (random and irregular shaped regions). I have a binarized version of what I would like the first filter applied to (attached). I'm not sure the best way to make a mask...I can load this binary image and use bwconncomp to locate connected components and define them as single vectors which won't work with poly2mask. Any suggestions for A. how to get a mask out of this binary image and B. how to use this mask to apply a filter to that part of the greyscale image?

Thanks in advance!

```
MASK=imread('/Users/bk/Desktop/FIJI_image/mask4.tif');
BACK=imcomplement(MASK);
I=imread('/Users/bk/Desktop/FIJI_image/Orig.tif');
I(~MASK)=0;
SE=ones(13,13);

A=stdfilt(I, SE);

minZ=min(min(A));
maxZ=max(max(A));
Low_High=[minZ maxZ];

var5=255/maxZ;
B=uint8(A*var5);

C=(imadjust(B,stretchlim(B),[]));
imtool(C);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binary image *is* a mask.

Given a grayscale image `I` and a binary image `M` with the *same size*, you can get the image `I` filtered by the mask `M` using:

```
J = I;
J(~M) = 0;
```

This is just masking. For filtering you can apply a filter on `I` with `imfilter` or any other one of MATLAB's filter functions. For example:

```
h = fspecial('motion', 50, 45);
K = imfilter(I, h);
```

Now you can get the original values of the pixels which are not in `M`:

```
K(~M) = I(~M);
```

So now `K` have filtered pixels in the locations where `M` is true, and untempered pixels in the locations where `M` is false.

Code for the example you added:

```
inputDir = 'temp2';
I = imread(fullfile(inputDir, 'PJlUm.png'));
M = imread(fullfile(inputDir, 'ewSPv.png'));
M = logical(M); % Convert M to a logical matrix, i.e. a mask.

Imasked = I;
Imasked(~M) = 0;

ImaskedAndStretched = Imasked;
ImaskedAndStretched(M) = imadjust(ImaskedAndStretched(M),stretchlim(ImaskedAndStretched(M)),[]);

IstretchedAtMask = I;
IstretchedAtMask(M) = ImaskedAndStretched(M);

figure;
subplot(3,2,1);
imshow(I);
title('Input Image');
subplot(3,2,2);
imshow(M);
title('Mask');
subplot(3,2,3);
imshow(Imasked);
title('Image Masked');
subplot(3,2,4);
imshow(ImaskedAndStretched);
title('Image Masked & Stretched');
subplot(3,2,5);
imshow(IstretchedAtMask);
title('Image Stretched At Mask');
```

The output:
[image: Output for example]

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I was doing initially..the issue I get when I do this (I'm using a stdfilt() filter and then do contrast stretching) is that I get a strange output from the processing around the edge of where the region of interest borders the background, also the contrast stretching seems skewed. Is there a way to keep the filter only convolving within the mask and ignoring the edges, and similarly to have the contrast stretching limited to the mask/region of interest?  Thanks!

Comment: The borders of the mask are "strange" because you are using a filter on one side of the border but not on the other side of it. You can blur the borders using `imgaussfilt` on pixels near the border. You can find the border pixels using `bwperim` or `bwboundaries` on the mask `M`. You can "widen" the border pixels using `imdilate`.

Comment: Regarding the contrast stretching - You can stretch only the filtered pixels using the mask. i.e. `I(M) =  imadjust(I(M),stretchlim(I(M)),[]);`. This is possible because the contrast stretching operation doesn't require neighborhood information, meaning the order and "shape" of the pixels in the image doesn't affect the result.

Comment: I've added the code I'm running and the output after running the filter/contrast stretch. It definitely looks like the stdev filter is incorporating finding strong standard deviation between the 0 background and the image within the mask rather than only filtering within the confines of the mask.

Comment: Can you please add the input image?

Comment: yup you got it, added